# WildFly 10, JCache - method caching

Tags: caching, spring-boot, infinispan, wildfly-10, jcache

i have simple application using Spring Boot. I wanted allow method caching with JSR107 - JCache. So with help of tutorial i put together this code :

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "testpoc")
public Country getCountry(Integer id){
    System.out.println("---> Loading country with code '" + id + "'");
    return new Country(id, "X", "Title");
}
```

with this POM file

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

(dependency 'spring-boot-starter-web' is there for simple REST service which call **getCountry** method)

Everything works like documentations says - method is invoked only once.

**Now i wanted to try it on WildFly 10 application server**

I have modified pom file :

- excluded tomcat
- exluded spring-boot-starter-cache
- added infinispan-jcache (because i want to use cache configured / managed by wildfly in standalone/domain.xml)

Check pom file [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8vMW6Vux).

Problem is, that i am receiving following error :
**Cannot find cache named 'java:jboss/infinispan/app-cache'**

(i have tried to use both JNDI assigned and name to infinispan cache configured in wildfly).

Following code created Cache object (so i can used it) :

```
CacheManager cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();
Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.createCache("testpoc", new MutableConfiguration<String, String>());
```

**Question** :

- It is possible to use JCache method caching on WildFly 10 using Infinispan managed by WildFly ?
- Or Infinispan should be used for method caching like JCache, hence JCache has "more functionality" than Infinispan.

Thank you very much

PS :It is not problem for me to put whole code on github and post link - it is few lines of code ...

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems with your approach so let me go through them in steps.

At first you need to use proper Infinispan setup. Infinispan bits shipped with WF should be considered as internal or private. In order to use Infinispan in your app properly - either add `org.infinispan:infinispan-embedded` to your deployment or install [Infinispan Wildfly modules](http://downloads.jboss.org/infinispan/8.2.4.Final/infinispan-as-embedded-modules-8.2.4.Final.zip). You can find installation guide [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#infinispan_modules_for_jboss_as_7_x) (it's a bit outdated but still, the procedure is exactly the same - unpack modules into WF and use `Dependencies` MANIFEST.MF entry).

Once you have successfully installed Infinispan (or added it to your app), you need to consider whether you want to use [Spring Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) or [JCache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-jcache). If you're only interested in using annotations - I would recommend the former since it's much easier to setup (all you need to do is to add [@EnableCaching](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html) to one of your configurations). Finally with Spring Cache you will create an Infinispan `CacheManager` bean. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/master/spring/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/spring/SpringCaching.java).

Final note - if you still need to use JCache - use [this manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-jcache) to setup Caching Provider.